# PUT/POST request sending without data

Tags: javascript, ajax, rest, pyramid

I have a client which makes the following request to a Pyramid Service.

```
var sendArr = {"hello": "world"};
$.ajax({
    type: "PUT",
    contentType: "application/json",
    url: "http://0.0.0.0:6543/" + obj.id + newUrlSegment,
    data: sendArr,
    headers: { 'X-User-Email': loggedUser.user, "X-Auth-Token": loggedUser.token},
    success: function(data,status,other){
        console.log("server return", data);
    },
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
        console.log(errorThrown);
    },
});
```

The request is received by the server, however the request 'data' is missing.

Is there any particular reason why the data is not being attached client-side?

Comment: Have you printed the data just before it gets sent to test?

Comment: Your code does not show the value of sendArr. Please add this information.

Comment: Are you sure sendArr is not empty?

Comment: Where are you setting the value of `sendArr`? Have you tested if it has a value using `console.log(sendArr)`?

Comment: Sorry, sendArr isn't empty, I have declared it above.

Comment: Try removing `contentType: application/json` and change to `contentType:application/x-www-form-urlencoded`
Please share your request payload.

Comment: `Console.log()`  `sendArr` and post the results into your question please

Comment: I had previously changed it to contentType:application/x-www-form-urlencoded which gave the same result as above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use:

```
data: JSON.stringify(sendArr)
```

It should work.

Comment: I can't believe I didn't notice that! Thanks!